# WMIC error: No Instance(s) Available (wmic product get name, version)

Tags: windows-10, wmi, wmic

I am trying to get the list of installed software in a brand new Windows 10 (Pro) machine.

In my case it seems some **wmic** commands work while others don't.

Find below two real examples:

```
$ wmic cpu get name
Name
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU@ 1.90GHz

$ wmic product get name, version
No Instance(s) Available
```

In order to fix the second one, do I need to configure or install anything?

I have another machine with Windows 10 (Enterprise) and both commands work fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This command only lists products installed by Windows Installer, not installers like InstallShield, Wise, NSIS. Have you installed any?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131413/wmi-get-the-list-of-installed-softwares

Answer (score 0):

I will use `Get-Package` in Powershell for this:

```
Get-Package |
  Where-Object {$_.ProviderName -in @('Programs','msi','chocolatey')} |
    Select-Object Name,Version
```

Comment: I switched the Windows version, from Pro to Enterprise and now it works. @Wasif, unfortunately I'm trying to access remotely from a Linux machine, and I don't know if wmic supports Powershell commands.